# Android Studio 3.6.1 issue with Android Material Design Icon Generator 1.9

Tags: java, android, android-studio, plugins

Please Help, i updated my android studio to the latest version 3.6.1 and now my Android Material Design Icon Generator 1.9 plugin is not working, i tried to look for an update, tried to remove and reinstall but nothing worked, its crashing with the following error message :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAllResourceDirectories()Ljava/util/List;
   at com.konifar.material_icon_generator.MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.initResDirectoryName(MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.java:318)
   at com.konifar.material_icon_generator.MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.<init>(MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.java:126)
   at com.konifar.material_icon_generator.MaterialDesignIconGenerateAction.actionPerformed(MaterialDesignIconGenerateAction.java:27)
   at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:265)
   at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:282)
   at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
   at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:265)
   at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:107)
   at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
   at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
   at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:82)
   at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
   at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:115)
   at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
   at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
   at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:524)
   at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:35)
   at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:546)
   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
   at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
   at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:823)
   at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
   at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:704)
   at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Is this Fixed? I am facing the same issue

Comment: I also logged the bug report on jetbrains plugins store, but up to now i havent got a response from them.

Comment: I've cloned this plugin and added new features and fixes. Do checkout.

[https://github.com/Dhaval2404/material-icon-generator-plugin](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/material-icon-generator-plugin)